# C++ char arrays initialising with wrong number of elements

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

When I initialise a cstring with a pointer as follows:

```
char* title = new char[endTitleChar - startTitleChar + 1];
```

...it initialises to char[24] regardless of the actual value of the expression in square brackets, which is anything from 12 to 1.

What's happening here?

Comment: What are `startTitleChar` and `endTitleChar` set to?

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, write `int const size = endTitleChar - startTitleChar + 1;` and use `new char[size]`.

Comment: Using `cout << title;` and counting the number of characters in the console output.

Comment: It's part of a loop for reading from a text file, so they vary, but one example is `startTitleChar = 1; endTitleChar = 12;`

Comment: Time to back up and regroup. Why are you doing this? Real uses for dynamic allocation of arrays are *exceedingly* rare. Chances are you shouldn't be doing this at all.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The short version is that I'm using arrays to store input from a text file which is converted into a string and stored in a `map<string,string>` containing, in this case, user preference data. This particular array is where I copy the "name" of the `map<string,string>` (for use in a `map<string,map<string,string>>` that stores different preference sets) without the formatting from the text file. Also, courtesy of Luchian Grigore commenting on the answer below, it turns out that the problem was that I wasn't adding a `'\0'` to the end of the array after copying the title.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't read directly from the file into a `string`?

Comment: Jerry makes a good point - why not use `std::string` directly?

Comment: It's very possibly a symptom of my inexperience with C++ string manipulation (and C++ in general), but it seemed much easier to strip the formatting that was in the original text file using a C-string.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question more specifically about how to read data in your specific format into a string (with whatever formatting removed that you don't want).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt that.

You get `endTitleChar - startTitleChar + 1` allocated characters back, but they have indeterminate value. If you do

```
char* title = new char[endTitleChar - startTitleChar + 1]();
//                                                    ---||---
```

you'll get them initialized to `0`.

Comment: That's not the case. I get 24 characters, all uninitialised.

Comment: @Watercleave as I said, I doubt that. How do you know how many you're getting back?

Comment: Using `cout << title;` and counting the number of characters in the console output.

Comment: @Watercleave feeding a C-string that is not null-terminated (like yours) to `cout` is undefined behavior. Ergo, that check is not valid. In fact, it's dangerous.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. C-strings will be the death of me... Much obliged.

Comment: @Watercleave Or it will make you battle hardended :)